# Gzip Notation in Red next to code in VS Code

Tags: reactjs

I am coding a website in React and Express. I notice that in my Express file in VS Code that next to the imported library there is a red notation with something about gzip. For example, my code said "import bodyParser from "body-Parser";" and next to it, VS Code writes "480.7k (gzipped: 210k) in red. Same thing for "import multer from "multer";" where it prints out "739.3k(gzipped:234.4k)" in red. Does this mean that VS Code didn't import the modules completely and if so, what should I do about it? Why does some other imported modules get printed in green with their gzip info?

Answer (score 1):

```
import bodyParser from "body-Parser"; 480.7k (gzipped:210k)
```

Let's consider the above line of code, it's saying that body parser is 480.7kbytes in size and when gzipped it can be compressed to around 210kbytes(It does varies considering your imports, modules and setup).

The colour coding
green : smaller size
yellow: medium size
red   : larger size

So red means the file size is larger and doesn't mean it's not imported correctly(Instead if it's determining the size, you can consider it imported).